# Parse nsstring json valuses in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, parsing, nsstring

I have JSon Values in NSString. I am trying to parse the values from the NSString JSonValue.

NSString Values like:

```
result =  [{"no":"01","send":"2010-05-03 01:26:48","from":"0000000000","to":"1111111111","text":"abcd"}]
```

I have tried the below code to parse the values no, send, from, to, text.

```
    NSString *jsonString = result;
    NSDictionary *jsonArray = [jsonString jsonValue]; //Am trying to save the values from NSString to NSDictionary the app getting crash here.
    NSLog(@"JsonDic : %@", jsonArray);
```

Can anyone please help to parse the JSon values from NSString? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have searched stackoverflow and couldn't find any questions about how to parse JSON on iOS? Very strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gopinath. I have mentioned code please try this one. I have tested i can get the no.

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];  

NSDictionary *jsonArray = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:result error:nil];  
NSLog(@"jsonArray : %@", jsonArray);

NSArray *depositArray = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"no"];
NSLog(@"depositArray : %@", depositArray);
```

Please test and let me know if you face any problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS5, you can use [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSError *error;
NSString *json = @"[{\"no\":\"01\",\"send\":\"2010-05-03 01:26:48\",\"from\":\"0000000000\",\"to\":\"1111111111\",\"text\":\"abcd\"}]";
id jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

And you can also use [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have solved the problem and i can get the values. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing JSON is a bit more complicated.

For my part, i use SBJSON, you can download it from here : http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

It is a simple set of file to put in your project. I suggest to put in a dedicated group.

Once you've done that, here is the code you could use :

```
NSError *jsonError;
NSDictionary *jsonResults;

SBJsonParser* parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
jsonResults = [parser objectWithString:YOURSTRING error:&jsonError ];

if (jsonResults == nil) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Something bad happened with JSON : %@ : %@",YOURSTRING,[ jsonError localizedDescription ]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
} else {   
   NSLog(@"JSON result : %@",jsonResults);

}
```

If you need more infos, you can find good tutorial on SBJSon, for instance here : http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/